# Get values of your attribute option text from product

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, store-view, attribute-options

I want to get value of attribute option text from product based on store id. I want to get admin text for attribute option.

```
$attribute_option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id,'my_attribute', $storeId);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setData('my_attribute', $attribute_option_id);

        $attributeText = $product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

I am always getting value of default store view. [image]

Comment: try again with remove $storeid from your script.

Comment: I tried using below snippet but still receiveing default store view value:

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attributeText=$product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');

Answer (score 0):

Create a function getAttributeAdminLabel() in your block and call this on page where you want.

```
$storeId = 1; //add you store id
$attribute_option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'my_attribute', $storeId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setData('my_attribute', $attribute_option_id);

echo $attributeText = $this->getAttributeAdminLabel('my_attribute', $product);

function getAttributeAdminLabel($attributeCode, $product) {
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product');
    $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);
    $_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setAttributeFilter($attributeModel->getId())
            ->setStoreFilter(0)
            ->load();
    foreach ($_collection->toOptionArray() as $_cur_option) {
        if ($_cur_option['value'] == $product->getMyAttribute()) {
            return $_cur_option['label'];
        }
    }
    return $item->getLabel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->load($product_id)
    ->getAttribute('color')
    ->getSource()->getOptionText($customer->getColor());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productAttribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');

$attriuteValue = $productAttribute->setStoreId($store_id)
                                  ->getSource()
                                  ->getOptionText($product->getData('my_attribute'));
```